# Ajax loading images but positioning is incorrect despite having same styling?

Tags: css, ajax

So Im loading images with ajax, except when they load they're positioning is mucked up, but the have exactly the same style and everything as the others. Scroll down to the bottom of this page to see what I mean.

http://alexbridger.com/test.php

And this is just my testbed site, I know it's awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some extra space characters in your html code between `<img>`. Those characters make some extra blank space between images in your site. So try to add this to `#maincontainer`:

```
#maincontainer {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

This will help, but you'd better check your code to find the strange extra space characters.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I would never have picked that up. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

well it sound weird but I found the reason. the difference between the pictures is there hieght and width, and the proportion between them. the pictures on the first rows originally were 304.904pxX306px. like a rectangle.
the pictures on the last row are 300X300 like a square.
the space you had on the first rows was not because on css, it was because the image was not a perfect square. try to upload images on the same size and add margin in the css file.

Comment: I wish this was the case but I can assure you they're the same size, there all 300X300. Have a look at [alexbridger.com](http://alexbridger.com) (theres no ajax it just loads the 8 images first time) they're the same images... Thanks anyway though. It's super annoying

Comment: I checked it again. use chrome, do inspect element on the divs with the pictures from the first row, and than do the same with the pictures from the last row. there is a difference